# Number of distinct ways to arrange n identical items into m places where m>n

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 6 slots and I have 3 identical marbles, the number of different ways I can arrange the marbles into the slots is 20 (e.g. xxx000, xx0x00, xx00x0, ...)

Is there a general formula for the number of ways n items can be placed into m places where m > n?

Update: The answer is provided by Bulbasaur below as follows:

m! / (n! x (m-n)!)

for example for n=3 and m=6, we have 6! / (3! x 3!) = 20

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Does the answer of $20$ for (6,3) ring a bell ?

Comment: **Hint:** You are choosing a subset of $n$ of the $m$ places to fill.  The order of selection does not matter.

Comment: Do you know *[COMBINATION WITH REPETITION](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/cs310-05s/notes/dm-gcomb#:~:text=Two%20combinations%20with%20repetition%20are,times%2C%20regardless%20of%20their%20order.&text=The%20number%20of%20combinations%20of,at%20a%20time%20with%20repetition.)* ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur  All we need to do here is select the subset of slots which will be filled with marbles.  This is just a combination problem.

Comment: Thanks, Bulbasaur! That was the solution: 6! / (3! x 3!) = 20, so in general m! / (n! x (m-n)!)

Comment: Yes, the answer is the number of $n$-element subsets of a $m$-element set, which is $\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{n!(m - n)!}$.  These are called [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).